How to change a single character in math mode with the same character from a different font in XeLaTeX?
I saw similar questions but looks like the answers provided do not directly apply to my question  or I cannot figure out how to do it for this particular case.
I'm using Xelatex and would like to change just a single letter in math mode and italics with the same letter from a different font. Let's say that I do not like the italic "g" from the font I am using in math mode/italics and would like to replace it with the italic "g" from another font.
The eventual answer would need to be applied to the already written document.
Is there a simple way of doing this?

Welcome to TeX.SX. It is always better to provide what you have and would like to attain. Providing a minimal working example expedites matters.

Well changing single letters to math mode is easy using $…$. You can change the font for maths separately from the font for text. But how to do that can differ depending on the compiler you use. So please add a MWE that shows your document set up.

Load \usepackage{unicode-math} and add the command
\setmathfont{Replacement-Math-Font.otf}[range={`}, Scale=MatchLowercase]

Several other variations for selecting a character will work, such as range="1D454, but with a math font, you must use the character from the Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols code block.
Then use \symit{g} rather than g in math mode, or define a command such as \g or \varg.   Example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Book}
\setmathfont{Fira Math}[range={`}, Scale=MatchLowercase, Color=DarkMagenta]

\begin{document}
\[ y(t) = y_0 + v_o t - \symit{g} t^2 \]
\end{document}


Now, if you want to take the g character from an italic font that’s not a math font and use it as your g in math mode, things get more complicated.  The simplest approach is to load your replacement font  with something like
\setmathfontface\mathvar{Replacement-Font-Italic.otf}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\newcommand\varg{\mathvar{g}}


Many thanks @Davidslor for your answer. Is there a way to solve this issue that does not involve using a new command for the replacement?

@user2171956 Load a math italic alphabet you like better, or a math font with a stylistic set/character variant for ``, for example STIX Two Math with StylisticSet=02.
